# print float without scientific notation in scala

Tags: scala

I want to convert float to 14 significant digits

```
val s = "1200000000".toFloat
```

Output-1.2E9

I tried below but does not work

`f"$s%1.0f"` but this doesnot work with all values
I want a method which takes in string and return a float .**The method can support upto 15 significant digits**

Comment: No, you haven't tried to print it that way. Could you share what have you tried?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: `f"$s%1.0f"` _does_ work for all values.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [toPlainString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString()) method of [java.math.BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
val floatValue = "1200000000".toFloat

new java.math.BigDecimal(floatValue).toPlainString 

res0: String = 1200000000
```

Comment: To set number of significant digits, use `new java.math.BigDecimal(floatValue).setScale(numDigits, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)`.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want exactly?

If you want to print a number with a given format you can use this:

```
println(f"$myNumber%1.14f")
```

The output will be:

```
1200000000.00000000000000
```

You can get more information [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html#the-f-interpolator)

Comment: I can have a string but doesnot want it to get converted to scientific notation but it can support upto 15 significant digits

Comment: 1200000000.00000000000000 is not 15 significant digits